# jquery slider Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, uislider

Running into an issue using jQuery `.slider()`. I'm using the most recent version of jQuery downloaded from [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) (using the UI and jQuery library from that download).

When the page loads the line that attempts to bind the slider to the div receives the following error

[image]

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsMVC")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/BackboneApps")
</head>
```

**BundleCollections**

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/BackboneApps").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/SliderApp.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsMVC").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/underscore.js",
                    "~/Scripts/backbone.js"));
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/SliderApp.js"></script>
</head>
```

**SliderApp.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize jquery slider
        $("#slider").slider();
        .
        .
    });
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <!-- "slider" is a jquery slider -->
    <div id="slider"></div>

    <!-- "sliderVal" displays the slider's position. It receives the value via model. -->
    <input type="text" id="sliderVal" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure jQueryUI is loaded? `console.log($.ui);`

Comment: and make sure jQuery isn't loaded again in page which wipes out plugins

Comment: make sure the jqueryui version which you are using contains definition for .slider() method..

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because, at the bottom of the page, a random

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

was entered. Since the jQuery library was loading twice the `ui` from above was blown away.

Comment: I also found this was the problem with mine. For some reason I'd called jquery twice, once below ui, and it got rid of it.